# Maximum distance between two different element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, integer

I have a problem where I need to find the maximum distance between two different elements in an array.

For example: given an array `4,6,2,2,6,6,4` , the method should return `5` as the max distance.

I am able to solve the problem using two for loops but it is not an optimized solution. Am trying to optimize it by doing it in a single for loop.

here is my current solution:

```
int [] A = {4,6,2,2,6,6,4};
int N = A.length;
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
        if(A[i] != A[j]){
            result = Math.max(result, j - i);
        }
    }
}

// tried below code but it is not efficient
//      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
//          
//          if(A[N-1] != A[i]){
//              result = Math.max(result, N-1-i);
//          }
//      }

System.out.println(result);
```

How to make this better in terms of time complexity?

Comment: How about have 2 arrays, the original array A and a reverse array R, for every element in A, get indexOf(element) in A and R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple (not *nested*) loop is enough, but *two cases* should be taken into 
account: either the best result is

```
  4,6,2,2,6,6,4
    ^         ^ - moving first
```

or

```
  4,6,2,2,6,6,4
  ^         ^   - moving last
```

for instance: `[4, 2, 4, 4, 4]` *moving first* brings the answer, when in case of `[4, 4, 4, 2, 4]` *moving last* should be used.

```
  int first = 0;
  int last = A.length - 1;

  // 1st case: moving "first"
  while (first < last) {
    if (A[first] == A[last])
      first++;
    else
      break;
  }

  int diff1 = last - first;

  first = 0;
  last = A.length - 1;

  // 2nd case: moving "last"
  while (first < last) {
    if (A[first] == A[last])
      last--;
    else
      break;
  }

  int diff2 = last - first;

  // result is the max between two cases
  int result = diff1 > diff2
    ? diff1
    : diff2;
```

So we have `O(N)` time complexity.

**Edit:** Let's proof that at least one of the indexes is either `0` or `length - 1`. Let's do it by *contradiction*. Suppose we have a solution like

```
  a, b, c, .... d, e, f, g
        ^ ..... ^  <- solution indexes (no borders)
```

Items to the left of `c` must be `d`, otherwise we can take `a` or `b` indexes and have an *improved* solution. Items to right of `d` must be `c` or we can once again push last index to the right and have a better solution. So we have

```
  d, d, c .... d, c, c, c
        ^ .... ^  <- solution indexes
```

Now, since `d <> c` (`c..d` is a solution) we can *improve* the solution into

```
  d, d, c .... d, c, c, c
        ^ .... ^           <- solution indexes 
  ^       ....          ^  <- better solution
```

We have a *contradiction* (the supposed solution is not one - we have a better choice) and that's why at least one index must be `0` or `length - 1`.

Now we have **2** scenarions to test:

```
  a, b, ..... y, z
     ^  ......   ^ <- moving first
  ^  ......   ^    <- moving last
```

We can combine both conditions into `if` and have just one loop:

```
  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i)
    if (A[i] != A[A.length - 1] || A[0] != A[A.length - 1 - i]) {
      result = A.length - i - 1;

      break;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why do we need to move to last?

Comment: @roger_that: quite agree, I'm sorry for my first terse response. Examples and the proof added.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I was thinking along the same lines as well. But i feel the code could be simplified a bit. Could you look into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single loop

Consider this.

The maximum difference between from a index `i` can be either between start element and `i` or  `i` and the last element

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v {4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 4};
    int start = 0, end = v.size() -1;
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(v[i] != v[start])
        {
            result = max(result, i);
        }
        if(v[i] != v[end])
        {
            result = max(result, end - i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The reason we are able to achieve a `O(N)` algorithm is because

Consider `v = [4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4]`

At index `i = 0` we check if we can find the maximum possible distance i.e with the last element but since they are same we can't consider it.

At `i = 0` for this array the maximum possible answer would have been 5.

```
[4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4]
 ^
```

At `i = 1` we again check both ends of the array still the same so we move on.

The real savings come here that we do not have to check for every other entry 
keeping the start at `i = 0`

So, at `i = 2`, we find that the maximum can be obtained with the end of the array

```
[4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4]
 ^     ^        ^
start  i       end
```

which is the same as keeping the `start` constant and keeping a runner loop.

Comment: Quite nice implementation of the idea; I'd rather stick to *array* `A` (as in the question)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you. I was actually referring to doing this with one loop instead of two while loops.

Comment: If you compare `v[i] != v[end] || v[start] != v[end - i]`, you can return on the first difference - or when `v.size()/2 <= i`: all elements equal.